# C# 3 operand in a statement

Tags: c#

I am writing the following codes

```
int a = 10;
int b = 12;
int c = 14;
int e = 18;
bool d = false;

a = b = c;            //Output
Console.WriteLine(a); //14
Console.WriteLine(b); //14
Console.WriteLine(c); //14


d = a != b;            //Output
Console.WriteLine(d); //False

d = a == b;           //Output        
Console.WriteLine(d); //True

a = b = c = e;        //Output  
Console.WriteLine(a); //18
Console.WriteLine(b); //18
Console.WriteLine(c); //18
Console.WriteLine(e); //18
```

I am unable to understand, how it works?

As we know that In C# if we are using more than two operands and more than one operator without any parentheses i.e ( and ) then.

**Case: 1 if operators’ precedence is different**

The operation will be performed on the basis of operator precedence.

E.g. 2+2/2 result will be 3 because the statement will be  2+ (2/2)

**But if operator precedence are same** for two or more than two operators then how is it processed?

Comment: There is three operators - assignment and two equality operators

Comment: Now I have explained in detail.

Comment: You can ask for more explanation of the question if someone feels it is not clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am unable to understand, how it works? What type of operator is it
>   called?

`=` is [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)

`a = b = c = e;` this is assignment done from right to left. So what ever `e` has is now held by a, b, c

[Assignment Operator - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx)

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand
>   in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand
>   operand and returns the value as its result.

If you are trying to compare values then you should use `==`. ([equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx))

Comment: More accurately, `c` is assigned the value of `e` first, and the new value of `c` is returned (`c = e`). Then, `b` is assigned the new value of `c`, and that value is returned. And so on.

Comment: @jia103 that's exactly what *from right to left* means :)

Answer (score 3):

`==` is a logic operator, that returns true if values are equal.

`=` is assignment operator, always parsed from right to left.

`!=` returns true, if compared values are unequal.

`!`  is a 1-side negation operator, which takes the bool value on the right of it and returns the oposite.

Answer (score 2):

Those statements are evaluated from right to left.
Also b = c returns new value of b

For a = b = c

First b = c is evaluated => b = c = 14
b now is 14 and expression becomes a = 14

similarly for d = a != b

a = 14, b = 14, a != b returns false
new expression is d = false

Hope you understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

I think single unclear thing here is [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx). You should understand, that it **returns** assigned value:

> The assignment operator (=) stores the value of its right-hand operand
>   in the storage location, property, or indexer denoted by its left-hand
>   operand and returns the value as its result.

I.e. `b = c` assigns value of `c` to local variable `b` **and** returns assigned value as result. Then `a = b = c` assigns this returned value to local variable `a` **and** returns assigned value.

To make things clear add brackets to show order of operations:

```
a = (b = c); // assign c value to b, then assign value of b to a
d = (a != b); // assign value of a and b comparison to d
d = (a == b); // same as above
a = (b = (c = e));  // everything becomes equal to e
```

Future reading: [C# Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In C# if you are using **more than two operands and more than one operator** without any parentheses i.e ( and ) then.

**Case: 1 if operators’ precedence is different**

The operation will be performed on the basis of operator precedence.

e.g. 2+2/2 result will be 3 because the statement will be  2+ (2/2)

**Case 2: when Operator precedence are same**

It is processed from right to left.

e.g int a, b, c, d, e;

…….

….

**a=b=c=d=e means (a= (b= (c= (d =e))))**

Or

If **a, b, c, d, e are operands and W,X,Y,Z are operators**

Then **a W b X c Y d Z e means (a W (b X (c Y (d Z e))))**